I have a Deere Jx75 gas powered mower that won't start when it is chilly outside
I can pull on this mower all winter when the average temperature is in the 40's and it won't turn over.  But when spring comes and it warms up to +70, it will start with one pull.  It the temperature drops it will get harder and harder to start, even if it was running a few hours ago. Replacing the spark plug made no difference.  Nor did blowing out the carb. Any ideas?  I want to exhaust as many possibilities as possible before I get it professionally serviced.

Did you replace the old gasoline and try adding anti-freeze additive?

I had a leaf vac with the same affliction that I had to use in freezing temperatures. Since professional service is against my religion -- I'm a devout DIYist -- I just used an old discarded hair dryer to heat up the carb for about a minute before starting on frigid days.
It worked and didn't cost me anything except a minute of my time.
You could also use a shot of starting ether in the air intake. One can would be good for many starts.
